# How to get Google Earth installed via .DEB?

Tags: deb, google-earth, purge

Now I've really messed things up.

A long time ago, I installed Google Earth via a binary installer from Google (v5.1, I think).

Google now has version 6 available as a .DEB, so I decided to install that. However, that seems to have messed up both installations and now no matter what I do, I can't get Google Earth to run.

Here's what I do:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-earth-stable
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Which I thought would work... but when I run `google-earth`, I get:

```
/usr/bin/google-earth: 43: ./googleearth-bin: not found
```

How can I get it installed now?

Comment: I think deb files are just archives - open it with archive manager and see where the "googleearth-bin" should be located and see if it's on your system (possibly not available on the $PATH)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this tutorial :

[install-google-earth-6-in-ubuntu-linux.html](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/install-google-earth-6-in-ubuntu-linux.html)

hope it help

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [page](http://www.google.com/earth/index.html) and click on the big blue button that says "Download Google Earth 6", this should give you the option of installing Google Earth as a .deb. Install it like you would any other .deb

Comment: That's what I did... and I've got the error above in my question.

Comment: oh my bad... lol guess I am of no use then

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the 32-bit version, then right clicked on it and choose "Extract Here" in nautilus.  That shows me the folder structure that would be installed if I installed the deb file.  It seems that the "googleearth-bin" file should be in `/opt/google/earth/free`.

I guess you'll need to check whether that exists on your system.  If not, perhaps the binary install has changed the permissions on that file in a way that breaks overwriting from the deb?  Not sure how that's possible given that you have to `sudo` to install a deb.

[image: Google Earth file structure]

It looks like the `/usr/bin/googleearth` is just a shortcut to that file too, not a script, so it's likely that there's something wrong in the /opt directory I mentioned above.

[image: File properties]

I guess you'll be best served by deleting the files/folders in the deb, then trying the re-install afresh?

Comment: Well, I completely removed the package and verified that `/opt/google/earth` was deleted... and it was.

Comment: It gets weirder: when I run `/opt/google/earth/free/googleearth-bin`, I get an error: `bash: ./googleearth-bin: No such file or directory` **even though the file exists and I can `stat` it.**

Answer (score 0):

First I'd go about uninstalling everything related to google-earth you can find.

The 5.1 binary installer defaults to `/opt/google-earth` as the install location, and also places a link in `/usr/local/bin` called `googleearth`. If you delete those two things, you should have successfully uninstalled the old version.

Next I'd do what you've already mentioned (again):

```
sudo apt-get purge google-earth*
```

Finally, use the `locate` command to see if there are some lingering files somewhere. This gets various permutations:

```
locate -i --regex "google.*earth"
```

Delete anything that shows up there (unless you're sure it's unrelated to the app). You may have a `.googleearth` directory in your user directory, which you could probably leave but maybe rename or delete it too if you still have problems.

Once you've cleaned everything out, then go install the .deb package again.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, actually, `sudo apt-get purge google-earth*` doesn't work because the package is named `google-earth-stable`.

Comment: apt-get handles `*` as a wild-character, so `google-earth*` should include `google-earth-stable`. That said, there's also the fact that on my machine the 5.1 .deb is called `googleearth`, so `google-earth*` won't catch everything!