# Programs don't start after installing .deb packages

Tags: 10.10, software-center, deb

I just installed a fresh copy of ubuntu destop 10.10 on my (old) Acer laptop. I downloaded Synergy and Google-Earth's deb file and it opened with the Ubuntu Software Center.

Now in the applications menu I see a google earth and a synergy option, but they don't do anything. Nothing opens.

Did I do something wrong? Was there something I needed to do?

Thanks

Comment: Try to launch the applications from the terminal and check for error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth has a known bug.  Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27607/how-to-get-google-earth-installed-via-deb/27617#27617) to see if fixes that problem.

I can't help with Synergy - as João Pinto observes in his comment, try running `synergyc` (if you want your Ubuntu PC to be a client) or `synergys` if your Ubuntu PC will be a server in a terminal window to see what output you get.